# can i use a 'LIKE' with a subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need some help with a query, in my database i have 3 unique columns, but sometimes we put some "characters" to create a new row. Now, I need to identify these cases, but there's a lot of rows (near of 50000), then I need to know which one of these are "duplicated" (not really duplicated, but the uniques fields are similar). Imagine you have two users that have the 'same' email, like

**email@enterprise.com
email+yourname@enterprise.com**

I need to know these cases, but with other columns like ID or username...

I've tried with subquery, but in the like clause i can only use one row.

I imagine something like...

```sql
select * from mytable where column like ('%'||select column from my table||'%);
```

I should get all the rows with 'duplicate-manipulate' data, so I can mix everyone.

Thanks! :D

Comment: Can you include more data and also better define what "duplicate" means here?

Comment: Like I said in the case of the email: myemail@enterprise.com and myemail+company@enterprise.com, or ID: 22 and 22b, these are the more common

Comment: Maybe some actual examples and what your expected output would be for those...  right now this is too notional to make sense of.

Comment: You are looking for duplicates between fields in one row, or between rows?  In the first case, you don't want a subquery at all.  In the second, you probably want a join or an EXISTS, not a regular subquery.  Your given example is going to be hard to solve with a LIKE, as putting the % at the beginning or the end is not correct.  You would need a regexp to put the % in the right stop, but at that point just use the regexp to solve the whole thing.

Comment: What is the actual format of the data?  That is to say, to get a correct answer, you are going to have to describe exactly how to tell the difference between 'actual characters' and the 'extra characters'.

Comment: For example, I had my own id, 25651, but also I have two more, 25651enterprise and 25651enterpriseb, so I need to seek for the first one and find the others... In the case of the email I should look for everything before the @, like: "myemail@enterprise.com" and "myemail+enterprise@enterprise.com", that's the actual format of the data. Some cases have something else, but there's at least one that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use the postgresql [similarity function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/pgtrgm.html), with join to the same table, I hope the example helps:

```
select u1.id, u2.id, u1.email, u2.email from mytable as u1 
join mytable as u2
    on similarity(u1.email, u2.email) >= 0.3 /* approach more than 1 for more similarity */
    and u1.id <> u2.id /* different primary key */
order by u1.id, u1.email, u2.email
```